# Simple, elegant manner of presenting parent/child CRUD operations

Tags: layout, gui-design

Consider the following grid:

[image: Grid]

The parent is comprised of "Code" and "Type", and each parent can have 0 or more children.  Each child is comprised of "Name" and "Type".

There's already a delete link to the left, which will delete the parent and its children.  I'm struggling with the best way to present an inline Create function which would allow the user to create a parent and (optionally) add children, as well as the ability to add and delete children of existing parent records.

Any suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what your entities are when you refer them only as parent and child. I've interpreted them to be Position and Person.

Maybe you could provide direct input for inserting new entities on the bottom row(s):

[image: direct input for creating entities]

If you feel that text boxes are too distracting (e.g. if there are lots and lots of rows) maybe a subtle hint text like "add new person" will do. Then it's possible to expand these hints to full input boxes on hover.

Also, missing in the picture are delete actions for individual persons.

Comment: that's pretty much the approach I was thinking of using, although I'm not sure how to approach the individual person delete action.  Perhaps a hover over the name would display a delete option?  All the field edit boxes will be dropdowns.

Comment: I'm a fan of this solution given how little information the question contains. For deleting the "children": put a small delete icon to the right of their position with a mouseover title explaining what it does.